# angularjs - get the filters attached to a directive

Tags: angularjs

Using `angular`, I have a situation where I've written a custom directive, and then some filters.

I have done a lot of searching, and haven't been able to find a clear way to actually get the filters out of the directive once attached. They are attached like this;

```
<div ng-data-bind="Model.Tags | format:'json'"></div>
```

The directive looks like ...

```
.directive('ngDataBind', ["$parse", "$filter", function($parse, $filter){
   return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
         ngDataBind: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
         // I am hoping to get the value of 'format' here (which is 'json' in this case)
      }
   }
});
```

Right now, the filter is just extremely bare bones. I haven't added any real functionality to it yet, because a lot of what I need to do is in the directive.

```
.filter('format', function(){
   return function(text, value) {

   }
});
```

So in the `ngDataBind` directive, that I wrote, I want to get the `format` filter and the parameter passed to it.

I've looked at the `$filter` service and it doesn't seem to do this. I've attempted to parse it off of the `attributes` parameter passed through `link` on the directive, but all that gives me is a huge string that isn't all that useful.

Is there any information on this, anywhere?

## Update

After being reviewed by people with a lot more experience in this than I have, I'm taking a different approach, since this is apparently not the appropriate use of filters.

The method I am going with is to create properties on the directive that are assigned like expressions, for instance..

```
<div c-data-bind="{ value: 'Model.Tags', format: 'json' }"></div>
```

I went with this method because there is a certain consistency in the expected input (always requiring content to be enclosed in `''` instead of mismatching between types of quotations) and it allows the directive to be expanded without having to add more directives later. I'm unsure if this is a good approach or not, but ... it *seems* to be working.

Comment: You question is unclear. Show us the code of your directive, of your filer, of the code using them, and tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: Certainly. Give me just a moment and I'll do so. I thought I did include code, I guess I was just absentminded.

Comment: Alright, I have updated it with what I thought I had put the first time.

Comment: The filter will filter the data model tags, and the result of the filter will be passed to your directive. Just like in JavaScript, `foo(bar(tags))` passes the result of `bar(tags)` to the function `foo()`. Inside of `foo()`, you don't care how the argument was passed to the function, and you can't know that `bar()` was called. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: really bad practice to use `ng` for your own directives. Could collide with future versions of angular

Comment: Hey @charlietfl, that's a really good point that I hadn't considered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is off. The directive should not concern itself with the filter.

The filter will process the bound data according to its logic.

The directive will receive the filtered data and act on it according to its logic.

None of the two need to know about the other. If you need them to, your design is flawed.

See [Separations of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information. I can concede to that, but can you tell me another way you would suggest passing in multiple options to a directive other than just making a ton of extra directives?

Comment: I would suggest to add additional attributes data-myns-format="json" for example. Do not use ng namespace this is reserved for angular core :)

Comment: Hey, I have updated the original post to describe how I solved this. If you want to see the final result, you can look at it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HiuUXRM26tJ0VyerP02q?p=preview - the reason for the directive, as huge and obscene as it is, was to make these widgets, which do not support full JSON objects right now, take real objects until Telerik issues a formal fix for this behavior.